# i would like to apply security constraints ,that allows only http methods like Get ,post only

Tags: java, http-headers, security-constraint

Case : 1 I used following .xml config in web.xml in servlets based

Still when i am trying to test it , other than get and post also allowed.

Can some suggest me the better approch for servlet based web application.

Comment: <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>wholesale</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    
</security-constraint>

Comment: Used this config in web.xml

Comment: IIRC Security constraints basically indicate that there needs to be authorization (e.g. like Basic Auth) .. That's different to REJECT particular HTTP code.